# BMP image header

Tags: bmp

I was observing header of 24 bit bmp image, it consists of 54 bytes

The 24 bit bmp image is given below:-

[image]

Then I converted same into monochrome bmp image using MS paint and I observed that its header consists of 62 bytes

The monochrome bmp image is given below:-

[image]

I am unable to understand why size of header have changed.

Answer (score 4):

BMP file header is build from file header (12B) and DIB header. There are different DIB headers, each of them have different size:

- BITMAPCOREHEADER (12B)
- BITMAPCOREHEADER2 (64B)
- BITMAPINFOHEADER (40B) - in your first file
- BITMAPV2INFOHEADER (52B) - in your second file
- BITMAPV4HEADER (108B)
- BITMAPV5HEADER (124B)

The reason that there are different headers is that Microsoft extended the DIB format several times. For compatibility reasons, most applications use the older DIB headers for saving files.

Comment: The BMP file header is 14 bytes...  two for the "BM", four for the file size, four reserved, and four for the start offset of the image data.

Comment: @Qiu That makes perfect sense. I didn't realize that MSPaint uses the V2 DIB header. You learn something every day.